# WordPress gutenberg editor is not associating Author id

Tags: wordpress

I registered a custom post type. However only the posts created from the Classic Editor within Admin panel have author id. And the notes created in Gutenberg editor have no author id( set to 0 ).

```
// register  Notes toye
$myargs = array(
    'show_in_rest' =>true,
    'public'=>false,
    'show_ui'=>true, //show in admin
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-write-blog',
    'supports'=>array( 'title','editor'),
     'labels'=>array(
         'name'=>'Notes',
         'singular_name'=>'Note',
         'add_new_item' => 'Add new Note',
         'edit_item' => 'Edit Note',
         'all_items' => 'All Note',
     ));
register_post_type( 'note', $myargs );
```

I am using 2 plugins only: Members by Justin Tadlock and Advanced custom fields.

Comment: Have you tried adding `'author'` to the `supports` array?

Comment: Not yet, let me try.